# Using FuzzyWuzzy with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I am trying to calculate the similarity between cities in my dataframe, and 1 static city name. (eventually I want to iterate through a dataframe and choose the best matching city name from that data frame, but I am testing my code on this simplified scenario).
I am using fuzzywuzzy token set ratio.
For some reason it calculates the first row correctly, and it seems it assigns the same value for all rows.

**code**:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

test_df= pd.DataFrame( {"City" : ["Amsterdam","Amsterdam","Rotterdam","Zurich","Vienna","Prague"]})


test_df = test_df.assign(Score = lambda d: fuzz.token_set_ratio("amsterdam",test_df["City"]))



print (test_df.shape)
 
test_df.head()
```

**Result:**

```
        City  Score
0  Amsterdam    100
1  Amsterdam    100
2  Rotterdam    100
3     Zurich    100
4     Vienna    100
```

If I do the comparison one by one it works:

```
print (fuzz.token_set_ratio("amsterdam","Amsterdam"))
print (fuzz.token_set_ratio("amsterdam","Rotterdam"))
print (fuzz.token_set_ratio("amsterdam","Zurich"))
print (fuzz.token_set_ratio("amsterdam","Vienna"))
```

Results:

```
100
67
13
13
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Please do not share picures of code . Why? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it via iterating through the rows:

```
for index,row in test_df.iterrows():
    test_df.loc[index, "Score"] =  fuzz.token_set_ratio("amsterdam",test_df.loc[index,"City"])
```

The result is:

```
        City Country Code  Score
0  Amsterdam           NL    100
1  Amsterdam           NL    100
2  Rotterdam           NL     67
3     Zurich           NL     13
4     Vienna           NL     13
```